# Integration using residual theorem.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How to compute the following integral?

$\int_C \frac{1}{z^5+3z+5} dz$, where $C: |z|=1$, taking positive direction.

I wanted to use residual theorem, but I got stuck computing residual points. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: I have corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One $|z|=1$, we have $|z^5+3z|\leq4<5$, so by Rouché's theorem, $z^5+3z+5$ has the same number of zeros inside the circle as does $5$. That is, the integrand is analytic on and within the contour.

By Cauchy's integral theorem, the integral is $0$.